# Сортировка двухмерного массива, который находиться в модификаторе private

Tags: php, ооп

есть массив в классе, который заключён в модификаторе private и как этот массив отсортировать в алфавитном порядке, вот так выглядит класс:

```
    class Notes {
    private $data = array(
    array('John Doe', '1997', '2000'),
    array('Alex Johnson', '1992', '1995'),
    array('Victor Stalker', '1985', '1991')
    )
  }
```

вот так выглядит файл, где подключен класс:

```
<?php
require_once "sort.php";
$object = new Notes();
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($object);
$method = $reflector->getProperty('data');
$method->setAccessible(true);
sort($method->getValue($object));
echo '<table cellpadding="25" cellspacing="2" border="1">';
foreach ($method->getValue($object) as $key1 => $array) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<th>". $key1 . "</th>";
    echo "<th>". "Имя" . "</th>";
    echo "<th>". "Срок" . "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $item ) {
      asort($item);

      echo "<td>"."Имя:"."</td>"."<td>" . $key2."</td>". "<td>" . $item . "</td>";

      echo "</tr>";
    }
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

То есть я вывел массив из класса с его значениями, но как мне теперь отсортировать в алфавитном порядке по его значению [0]. Прошу любую подсказку или намёк как с помощью метода array_multisort отсортировать правильно, то у меня не выходит это дело.

Comment: Можно создать `public` метод `GetSortData` в классе `Notes`, который будет сортировать и возвращать массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете добавить этот метод в ваш класс как предложил @dexploizer

```
public function getData()
{
   usort($this->data, function($a, $b) {
        return $a[0] <=> $b[0];
    });
   return $this->data;
}


<?php
require_once "sort.php";
$object = new Notes();
$filteredArray = $object->getData();
echo '<table cellpadding="25" cellspacing="2" border="1">';
foreach ($filteredArray as $key1 => $array) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<th>". $key1 . "</th>";
    echo "<th>". "Имя" . "</th>";
    echo "<th>". "Срок" . "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $item ) {

      echo "<td>"."Имя:"."</td>"."<td>" . $key2."</td>". "<td>" . $item . "</td>";

      echo "</tr>";
    }
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, а как правильно вывести метод getData в в моем файле(то что верху)?еще раз спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Остин дополнил ответ